# como puedo mapear la siguiente API con .map javascript

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Hola Amigos estoy hacieendo una app en react, tengo la siguiente API http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dc3c053300000540034757b creo un useState de la siguiente forma:

`let [topFiveMovie, setTopFiveMovie] = useState([]);`

```
useEffect(() => {
   let getTopFiveMovies = async () =>{
       let url = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dc3c053300000540034757b';
       let res = await fetch(url);
       // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
       topFiveMovie = await res.json();
       setTopFiveMovie(topFiveMovie);
       console.log(topFiveMovie);          
   }
   getTopFiveMovies()
}, [])
```

`

al momento de querer mapear esta info en otro componente me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentando de todo y no se como mapear esta api para mostrar los resultados en pantalla. Agradeceria su ayuda.

gracias

Comment: No estas mapeando nada (literalmente no llegas a mapear nada), de todas maneras no veo donde dices que usas `.map`.

Comment: la variable de estado topFiveMovie la pongo como prop en otro componente y desde ese componente trato de mapearla

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te devuelve un objeto, debes usar la propiedad movies que es el array
SetTopFiveMovie(topFiveMovie.movies)

`let [topFiveMovie, setTopFiveMovie] = useState([]);`

```
useEffect(() => {
   let getTopFiveMovies = async () =>{
       let url = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dc3c053300000540034757b';
       let res = await fetch(url);
       // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
       topFiveMovie = await res.json();
       setTopFiveMovie(topFiveMovie.movies);      
   }
   getTopFiveMovies()
}, [])`
```